# Separate list from a list Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have this:

```
Lines=[['4'],['1','2','3','4'],['5','6','7','8'],['9', '10']]
```

And i want:

```
a=['4']
b=[['1','2','3','4']['5','6','7','8']]
```

To do this, I have to search for the elements inside of Lines that have length=a=['4'].

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please provide your attempt? For several reasons you will more likely get a good answer when showing effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can do with a "one-liner":

```
Lines=[[4],[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9, 10]] ,
selectchk([Len], Lines, Lines0) ,
length(LineOfLen, Len) ,
findall(LineOfLen, member(LineOfLen, Lines0), LinesOfLen) .
```

Result in swi-prolog (ignoring the less-important variables):

```
Len = 4,
LinesOfLen = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]].
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple one-liner:

```
select_sublists( [[L]|Xs] , Ys ) :-
  findall( X , (member(X,Xs), length(X,L)) , Ys ).
```

In the head of `select_sublists/2`, we ensure that the head of the passed-in list (the first argument) is a single element list containing the desired length. We extract that length, and use the tail as the list-of-lists to be searched.

The invocation of `findall/3` in the body says:

- find all `X`, such that
- `X` is a member of `Xs`, and
- the length of `X` is `L`,
- returning the result list in `Ys`.

Running

```
Lines = [ [4] , [1,2,3,4] , [5,6,7,8] , [9, 10] ] ,
select_sublists( Lines, Filtered).
```

gives you the expected

```
Filtered = [ [1,2,3,4] , [5,6,7,8] ]
```

Comment: I had this error:
uncaught exception: error(type_error(integer,'4'),findall/3)

I said wrong. My Lines is [ ['4'] , ['1','2','3','4'] , ['5','6','7','8'] , ['9', '10'] ] and not [ [4] , [1,2,3,4] , [5,6,7,8] , [9, 10] ]

Comment: '4' is an atom, so add atom_number/2 to convert '4' (an atom) into 4 (integer).
https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=atom_number/2